# Given the equation $x^2+zw+zx=0$, find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given the equation

$x^2+zw+zx=0$,

find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$, assuming that $x$ is a function of $z$ and $w$.

My attempt: We differentiate both sides with respect to $z$ and find

$2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} + w + x + z\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=0$

$\implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{-x-w}{2x+z}$.

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's good.